# Creating navbar with jQuery: problems with background

Tags: jquery, click, background-color, mouseenter, mouseleave

I am having a problem with on() and off(). I created a navbar for which I want the div to be blue when you are with your mouse on top of it or when it is the last one clicked.

Therefore I used the mouseenter/ mouseleave (as I want the color to change gradually) and I used off() and on() as when the div is clicked (as the last one) is should not change with mouseenter/ mouseleave.

The problem is that with the code which I have below the mouseenter() mouseleave() events do not occur anymore when the div is clicked, can anyone help me with this? I used importance notation as well which does not work, and I really want to keep using jquery and the mouseenter/ mouseleave functionality. Thanks in advance!

```
$('.blok_nav').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate(
        {backgroundColor: "blue", color: "red" }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
}   )

$('.blok_nav').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate(
        {backgroundColor: "red", color: "blue" }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
}   )

$('.blok_nav').click(function(){
    $('blok_nav').not(this).on().css("background-color", "red").css("color", "blue")
        $(this).off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave').css("background-color", "green").css("color", "red")
})
```

Comment: Can you make [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the animations to occur for all but the last `.blok_nav` element? In which case you could use `$('.blok_nav:not(:last)')` as the selector for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and delete the `click` function

Comment: I don't understand your question. But here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX8NR/) for you.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I mean that when div 1 for example is clicked. That this div will be "highlighted" and therefore not change when hover over (With mouseenter/ mouseleave). When another div is clicked, this div will be highligted (and div 1 will change to normal). The problem is that the hovering does not work anymore when the div is not highlighted anymore and i don't understand why and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fX8NR/5/  So as you can see when you clcik the div's/boxes they stay blue and the hover effect disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `css transitions` to achieve what you want and then apply a class when an element is clicked to highlight that element and remove the transitions

CSS

```
.block_nav {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.highlighted {
  color:white;
  background:green;
}

.blok_nav:not(.highlighted){
  color:blue;
  background-color:red ;
}

.blok_nav:not(.highlighted):hover {
  background-color: blue; 
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
  color: red;
  transition: color 500ms linear; 
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.blok_nav').click(function() {
  $('.blok_nav').removeClass('highlighted');
  $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

[Refer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fX8NR/9/)

Note: `transition` is not supported in earlier versions of IE

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect! I did not know that you had the transition effect is css! Thanks a lot!